# How do I rebase a subtree?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I am experimenting with [Git subtree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) and I need some help.

I have a repo `A`, with a subtree, generated from an upstream repo `B`, in folder `A/b`. There is a file in the upstream `B/x`, and I can see that the equivalent file `A/b/x` exists and is up to date. If I first modify the upstream file `A/b/x`, and the downstream file `B/x`, when I call `git subtree push ...` I get a merge conflict, as expected.

I can do a `git subtree pull ...` which performs a merge which is applied over my `B/x` edit. I would prefer to do a `rebase` operation where my change to `B/x` is applied over the `A/b/x` edit.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Git subtree doesn't seem to support rebase (as one of two methods of "integrating" changes: rebase or merge). There is one [TODO](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/todo) mentioning rebase, but I think it's in a different context.

The subtree pull command doesn't even issue a git pull command, but splits it into the two necessary commands, fetch + merge, or I would suggest overriding pull's default integration strategy (`pull.rebase`).

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh#L870

If I understand your scenario correctly, I think you should *avoid* modifying `B/x` directly in its repository. Subtree allows you to modify `A/b/x` and to use `subtree push` to send the changes to the subtree's remote.

Either way, subtree isn't really "rebase" aware. You could always rebase the `B` remote directly, but you would still need to merge unrelated histories in `A`. That gets tricky and, for me, seems to require interactive rebase.